# show that solutions which start in the first quadrant must remain there for all time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that all solutions $x(t)$, $y(t)$ of $$x' = x^2+y\sin{x}$$ $$y' = -1+xy+\cos{y}$$ which start in first quadrant ($x, y >0$) stay there for all time. I have seen same questions on this site but i do not understand provided answers. I realize that on boundaries i.e when $x = 0$ then $x'=0$ and when $y = 0$ then $y' = 0$. I do not see why would that mean that $x$ or $y$ stay equal to 0 whenever the trajectory first enters either boundary, which seemed to be main point of answers I saw. I tried computing trajectories from $\frac{dy}{dx}$ but its not easily solvable if at all, so i dont think that is the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is the local uniqueness of solution.

The time invariant system $f((x,y)) = \begin{pmatrix} x^2+ y \sin x \\ -1 +xy + \cos y \end{pmatrix}$ is locally Lipschitz, so the solutions are unique.

We prove the claim by contradiction, assuming that there's a solution starting inside the positive quadrant, but reaching $x=0$ after some (positive) time, and derive a contradiction.

Suppose $(x,y)$ is a solution starting from $x(0)>0, y(0)>0$
and let $T$ be the smallest positive $T$ such that $x(T) = 0$.

Let $z$ solve the system $z' = -1+ \cos z$ with $z(T) = y(T)$.

Then $t \mapsto (0, z(t))$ solves the original system (we only care about locally) and passes through $(0,y(T))$, hence $(x(t),y(t)) = (0, y(t))$ which contradicts $x(t) >0$ for $t \in [0,T)$.

In a similar manner, suppose $T$ be the smallest positive $T$ such that $y(T) = 0$. Let $w$ solve the system $w'=w^2$ with $w(T) = x(T)$, then
$t \mapsto (w(t),0)$ solves the original system (we only care about locally), which contradicts $y(t)>0$ for $t \in [0,T)$.

Hence the solution remains in the interior of the first quadrant for as long as the solution exists.

Comment: This is a great answer, but let me place a comment between the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs: "...are unique. We prove the claim by contradiction, assuming that there's a solution starting inside the positive quadrant, but reaching $x = 0$ after some (positive) time, and derive a contradiction. (We could equally well consider reaching $y = 0$, and the argument is similar). So... Suppose $(x, y)$ is a solution starting from ..."

Comment: @JohnHughes My powers of exposition are limited and long out of practice! I will plagiarise your suggestion.

Comment: Happy to contribute. Sometimes I think my powers of exposition are all I have left.:)

Comment: Got very similar question on exam and recieved full points thanks you your great explanation :) Thank you